# React login validation with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to implement login in my react application with hooks. I am using useEffect hook to call the api to get the credentials. After receiving the credentials I am updating the state in context. But It seems the state is not updating. What I am doing wrong?

```
useEffect(() => {
            async function fetchdata(){
            try {
                var url = 'http://localhost:3292/ExamService.svc/getuser/'+ user +'/'+ pass;
                var output = await fetch(url).then((result) => result.json());
                setLogUser(output[0].Name); 
                setIslogin(true); 
            }
            catch {
                console.log('error')
            }
        }

        if(isLoading === true){
            fetchdata();
        }
         
    },[isLoading])

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    
    setLoading(true);
    console.log(isLogin); // it is coming false
    
  }
```

Comment: And what `isLoading` is supossed to be? Where it's declared and what happens after that? Share a bit more.

Comment: isLoading is declared in the component with useState and is being used to show loading indicator when data is being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing asyncronous and syncronous code in a weird way. The isLogin console.log is false because the promises inside the useEffect have not solved yet. In fact you don't need useEffect for doing this, I think this snippet would be cleaner in this way

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3292/ExamService.svc/getuser/'+ user +'/'+ pass;
        const output = await ( await fetch(url) ).json()
        setLoading(false)
        return output
    }
    catch(err){
        setLoading(false)
        console.log(err)
    }
}

const handleSubmit = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const authData = await fetchData()
    if(authData){
        setLogUser(authData[0].Name); 
        setIslogin(true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: the code is getting the data but after if(authData) the two setState statements are not triggering. logUser is coming empty and isLogin is false.

Comment: Where are you putting the statement to know the value of logUser and isLogin?